# Open a dialog window from a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have created a windows service application in C# to popup a dialog window at particular intervals. While debugging in Visual studio, it is working well. Then I created an installation setup. But after installing the service is not firing to popup the dialog window.
What will be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't do this, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12956489/261050. See other answers to that question for workarounds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [show a windows form from a window service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953148/show-a-windows-form-from-a-window-service)

Comment: If i face this problem i will do this. Put `Try Catch` and `log` the exception into File. and see., :)

Comment: @RJK the logged exception won't discuss session 0 isolation and the non-interactive nature of that session

Answer (score 3):

Services run in session 0 which is isolated from the interactive desktop. You cannot show UI from a service. You need to run a separate desktop process to show the UI and then use IPC to communicate between the service and the desktop process.

If your dialog is simple enough you could possibly use [WTSSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to run code at regular intervals then you may be better off with a scheduled task rather than a service.

Answer (score 1):

How is your service installed? What windows Version are you on?

If vista/7 does Interactive services Detection show up?

Bottom line is windows services where never designed for user interaction.

There is a way however, but I would recommend using a different way to interact with the user

Setting a windows service to interact with the desktop could pose a security issue.

I posted this link Hope it helps

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/1c3d4b96-c58b-465a-a964-89926bd455f1/