# is there a way to use winrm locally to invoke an UI dialog on the remote machine

Tags: chef-infra, knife, winrm

I'm using chef to deploy windows instance. In a situation, I need to run an "notepad.exe" (take notepad as an example) command on the newly launched machine and expect the notepad dialog pops up. Currently I use "**knife winrm 'ip' 'chef-client' -m -x user -P 'pwd'**" command to do the chef-client. while I tried many ways using different chef resources, like batch,execute. all failed. Anybody know how to use chef or winrm command to invoke ui dialog like notepad on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

WinRM runs in a service context, so it doesn't have access to the GUI session as far as I know. This is both for security reasons and to guard against terribly written services. Check out answers like [Open a dialog window from a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272865/open-a-dialog-window-from-a-windows-service) for more information on running interactive applications from the service context. A common workaround is to setup a scheduled task to run in 1 minute or similar, but even that has weird side effects at times.

Comment: thanks for your comments. If I use the schedule task as a workround, is there a good way to track when the task is finished ? so I could do other things following.

Comment: No, there is not. Windows is specifically designed to make this difficult, you'll need to rewrite stuff to be headless if you want it to work smoothly.

Comment: yes, this really bothers me .anyway, thanks for your comments.