# IIS8 with third party window

Tags: c#, iis, text-to-speech, iis-8

I used System.Speech for generation voice messages. Also I user third party commercial voice (Hebrew language)

Here is my code:

```
using (var ss = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    ss.SelectVoice("Aharon Ron");
    ss.SetOutputToWaveFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "2.wav"));
    ss.Speak("שלום");
}
```

If I run it from Visual Studio IIS Express first time I get voice activation window
[Activation window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEXWl.png)

If I try to use it on real server with IIS 8. I can't to see that window and I can't to activate voice.
How I can to show the window from IIS process?

P.S. 
I sent request to voice producer support, but I did not get response yet.

Comment: That window displays on the server. It can't display on the client. Activate the software once on the server.

Comment: Sure, I can see server desktop via RDP, but there is not window.

Comment: You [cannot see it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16272937/11683) because it originates from the IIS process which is a service. If that dialog box is the only activation mechanism available, create a standard exe that uses this component, run it on the server to register the component, then it will work from IIS.